SHA256 hash for Netezza
I am working on an application that provides connectivity to Netezza Performance Server(NPS) 7.2 and trying to use SHA256 authentication mechanism to achieve the same. I have tried using the SHA256 algorithm in its standard form and generate a hash by making use of the password and salt in different ways but that doesn't seem to work and I always get wrong password error. Do we have any information regarding how SHA256 works with NPS and how can I create the hash correctly in this case? Any help will be much appreciated as I have not been able to find much on my own so far.

Maybe the answer is in the doc
